# How can mkntfs be used to create a Windows filesystem on a file?

Tags: linux, ntfs

According to the man page:

> MKNTFS(8)
>   ...
>
> mkntfs is used to create an NTFS file system on a device (usually a disk partition) or **file**.

The problem is that when I give it a pre-created 64GB file as an argument it wants a device:

```
] mkntfs share1.dat # share1.dat is a pre-created 64 GB file

share1.dat is not a block device.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!
```

How do I get it to accept the share1.dat file as a file and create an NTFS filesystem on this file that I can later mount and share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force it with the `-F` option:

```
mkntfs -F share1.dat
```

This also disables safety checks for mounted volumes, so take care...